# With a public getter and setter of a private property, the property becomes public?

Tags: java, oop

I do not understand why a property should be made private when there also are a public getter and setter.

```
class C{
  private int i;

  public int getI(){return i;}
  public void setI(int i){this.i=i;}
}
```

Now the private property i is made public. It is as if you had done

```
class C{
  public int i;
}
```

Or do I not understand something?

Comment: *the property becomes public* - Well, **access to that property becomes public**. We will have more control over the way the property is accessed.

Comment: No, because your `setI` could have logic which could control the way in which `i` get's changed, you have no such control with your second example

Comment: I understand, but Eclipse generates the getter and setter as above, and almost always it is kept this way, and I was wondering what the use of this pattern is.